# RN 0.61.1 Build failed 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

*To the mods: before you mark this as a duplicate, let me assure you that I've gone over every similar thread, but that I needed to create one because the answers don't apply to the RN version I'm using*

After upgrading from 0.60.5 to 0.61.1 I'm getting the following error for libraries that I have statically linked in my app:

[image: error description]

```
React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found
```

Also, in the `Edit Schemes -> Build` section the React dependency seems to be missing.

[image]

Does anyone know what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by removing all static linking references within XCode, and using Cocoapods for dependency management. Something seems to have broken with regards to static linking in the RN version I used.